# Angular ng-class does not compile/work

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

ng-class directive does not compile and in inspector visible as is at runtime.

ts script

```
export class TotalPage {

  showClass: boolean;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController ,public http: Http) {

        this.showClass = false;

  }

}
```

html

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Total</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <div ng-class="{expenceBg:showclass}">Test</div>  
</ion-content>
```

scss

```
$expence-bg: #ffcccc;
$income-bg: #00cccc;
page-total {
    .expenceBg{
        background-color: $expence-bg;
    }
    .incomeBg{
        background-color: $income-bg;
    }
}

.expenceBg{
        background-color: $expence-bg;
    }
```

So when I run it it have Test so it does not compile that "ng-class" section. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try as `[ngClass]="{expenceBg:showclass}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-class` is used only in AngularJS, not Angular (2+). Use `[ngClass]` instead.

```
<ion-content padding>
  <div [ngClass]="{expenceBg:showclass}">Test</div>  
</ion-content>
```